# Where did this white space came from?

Tags: html, css

I am having problems with my `sidebar_box`, as it is displaying a unwanted white space at the bottom of my images.

The thing is that this seems to happen only when I place an image inside (this doesn't happen with text or ul lists)

You can see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sKE6y/)

**My HTML structure:**

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar_box">
        <div class="sidebar_header">Advertisement</div>
        <img src="./images/square_add.png" width="180" height="150" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**The relevant CSS to reproduce:**

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

img{
    border:0;
}

#sidebar .sidebar_box{
    width:180px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

#sidebar .sidebar_header{
    width:180px;
    background:#ddd;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```

I am clueless and I have already tried everything of my knowledge.

Comment: Maybe if you specify the height of the div's? would help? http://jsfiddle.net/sKE6y/

Comment: @FeRtoll you linked to my jsFiddle

Comment: sry http://jsfiddle.net/sKE6y/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: bottom` to your image. This happens because images are displayed inline, meaning they have to leave space below in case of `q`, `p` or other letters that drop below the baseline.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thanks a lot, you have saved around 100 hairs of my head

Answer (score 2):

write this:

```
img{
    border:0;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Check this  http://jsfiddle.net/sKE6y/1/